# PostgreSQL - COPY FROM - "unacceptable encoding" error

Tags: postgresql, encoding, copy

I get an error when trying to use copy utility to extract data from csv file with UCS-2 LE BOM encoding (as reported by notepad++).

```
COPY pub.calls (............ ) 
FROM 'c:\IMPORT\calls.csv'
WITH 
  DELIMITER ','
  HEADER
  CSV
  ENCODING 'UCS2';
```

The error is something like this

> SQL Error [22023]Error The argument of encoding parameter should be
>   acceptable encoding name.

UCS-2 gives the same error.

Comment: I would suggest you trying to use `ENCODING 'UTF8'; `?.. I don't know if all UCS-2 codes match those in UTF, but I thought so for some reason... :)

Comment: UTF-8 gives wrong byte sequence..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the list of supported charsets:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html

or in `psql` type `\encoding` and dbl tab for autocomplete:

```
postgres=# \encoding
BIG5            EUC_JP          GB18030         ISO_8859_6      JOHAB           LATIN1          LATIN3          LATIN6          LATIN9          SJIS            UTF8            WIN1252         WIN1255         WIN1258
EUC_CN          EUC_KR          GBK             ISO_8859_7      KOI8R           LATIN10         LATIN4          LATIN7          MULE_INTERNAL   SQL_ASCII       WIN1250         WIN1253         WIN1256         WIN866
EUC_JIS_2004    EUC_TW          ISO_8859_5      ISO_8859_8      KOI8U           LATIN2          LATIN5          LATIN8          SHIFT_JIS_2004  UHC             WIN1251         WIN1254         WIN1257         WIN874
```

Comment: No.. iconv is for linux and I use windows on this PC. Trying to do this with powershell..

Comment: ah, right, np++ - does not it convert itself? I recall it's extremely powerful. Probably my best experienced text processor

Comment: Yes, np++ can handle it, but I want to automate it. Now I use powershell script:         Get-content -encoding "Unicode" 'c:\IMPORT\calls.csv' |out-file -encoding UTF8 'c:\IMPORT\calls_out.txt'